# Strange behavior with CloudFormation updating SNS Topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Apologies for the long read, but I have only included the relevant parts necessary. I have inherited some code and CloudFormation scripts for a project and the previous developer left a cryptic note:

> You must update the trailing date on the following items in app-deploy.cfn.yaml to get changes to take effect.

He's long gone and not somewhere I can ask him about his instructions. Here are the items that must be updated:

```
ApiDeployment20200214:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi

RestApiStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiDeployment20200214
      RestApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi
      StageName: !Sub ${Environment}

ApiBasePathMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    DependsOn: ApiDeployment20200214
    Properties:
      BasePath: ''
      DomainName: !Ref ApiGatewayDomainName
      RestApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi
      Stage: !Sub ${Environment}
```

Honestly, this seems way out of the ordinary. It looks like he is applying cache-busting techniques to the API Gateway. This, to my knowledge, should not ever have to happen.

Boy was I wrong.

I recently needed to make one simple change to an SNS Subscription, adding only `- redirect` as a source for a particular Lambda subscription. Here is that resource with the new source added:

```
BHIEventLambdaSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !GetAtt BHIEventLambdaFunction.Arn
      Protocol: lambda
      TopicArn: !Ref EventTopicArn
      FilterPolicy:
        domain:
          - payments
        source:
          - recycling
          - processor
          - paas
          - redirect
        type:
          - payment.approved
          - payment.declined
        brand_id:
          - '40'
```

I deployed the scripts and witnessed the updates take place. I checked the console for the proper JSON, revealing this:

```
{
  "source": [
    "recycling",
    "processor",
    "paas",
    "redirect"
  ],
  "type": [
    "payment.approved",
    "payment.declined"
  ],
  "domain": [
    "payments"
  ],
  "brand_id": [
    "40"
```

All good! I should be good to go, but when I sent the proper message to test the source I got an error message:

> @message
>   2020-02-14 19:11:02 <071acec7-096b-4c45-996a-5ed996df7c23> ERROR AbstractEventHandler:66 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to process message, Invalid format.

And in my UI

```
{"message": "Invalid request body"}
```

Checking the CloudWatch Logs I can see the request being properly made with that source:

> @message
>   2020-02-14 19:13:41  INFO BHIEventHandler:23 - BHI Handler Received: {[{sns: {messageAttributes: {domain={type: String,value: payments}, **source={type: String,value: redirect}**, type={type: String,value: payment.approved}, brand_id={type: String,value: 40}}, ....

---

Suddenly I recalled the cryptic message from the previous developer, but I could not see how that would apply to make a change to SNS, especially since that update appeared to be deployed to AWS properly. Another developer who I was discussing this with said, "You could just prove old Bruce wrong by trying it, you've got nothing to lose at this point and we can eliminate that as a distraction."

Off we go, we change the dates assigned/appended/tagged to the API resources and redeploy. I see the updates in the console, CodePipeline reports the deployment has been completed successfully. We send the test...

...and the dang thing worked!

**My Question**

Why does making a change to a completely (apparently) unrelated portion of CF make this work? Have we done something wrong? If so, how do I correct this?

**By request**

Here is the complete template:

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
  DeveloperPrefix:
    Type: String
    Default: ''
  AppName:
    Type: String
    Description: The application name
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: The environment name
  AppVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: The application version
  SharedBucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: Shared bucket name containing the deployable artifact
  WorkspacePrefix:
    Type: String
    Description: App workspace in shared bucket
  DeployPhase:
    Type: String
  CustomResourceLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The Custom Resource Lambda S3 version of the artifact
  S3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The S3 Version
  HGEventLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The HG Event Lambda S3 version of the artifact
  HGEventRetryLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: HG Event Retry Lambda S3 Version artifact
  SBEventLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The SB Event Lambda S3 version of the artifact
  SBEventRetryLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: SB Event Retry Lambda S3 Version artifact
  BHEventLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The BH Event Lambda S3 version of the artifact
  BHEventRetryLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: BH Event Retry Lambda S3 Version artifact
  BHIEventLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The BHI Event Lambda S3 version of the artifact
  BHIEventRetryLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: BHI Event Retry Lambda S3 Version artifact
  AsoEventLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The ASO Event Lambda S3 version of the artifact
  AsoEventRetryLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: ASO Event Retry Lambda S3 Version artifact
  CTEventLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The CT Event Lambda S3 version of the artifact
  CTEventRetryLambdaS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: The CT Event Retry Lambda S3 Version artifact
  HZ:
    Type: String
    Description: The hosted zone in Route53
    Default: "notifications.svcs.example.com"
  CloudFrontHZ:
    Type: String
    Default: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
  VPCStackName:
    Type: String
    Description: "The Stack containing the VPC you wish to attach the VPN to"

Mappings:
  EnvironmentMap:
    dev:
      EnvironmentName: 'dev.'
      CertificateId: ''
      HostedZoneId: ''
      VpcStackName: VPC-QA
    qa:
      EnvironmentName: 'qa.'
      CertificateId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      HostedZoneId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      VpcStackName: VPC-QA
    stage:
      EnvironmentName: 'stage.'
      CertificateId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      HostedZoneId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      VpcStackName: VPC-Stage
    prod:
      EnvironmentName: ''
      CertificateId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      HostedZoneId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      VpcStackName: VPC-Prod

Conditions:
  IsMainPipeline: !And
    - !Equals [ !Ref DeveloperPrefix, '' ]
    - !Equals [ !Ref DeployPhase, rel ]

Resources:
  #####################
  # HostedZone Config #
  #####################
  HostedZoneResource:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${SharedBucketName}/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}/${Environment}/cf/nested/${S3Version}/hosted-zone.cfn.yaml"

  ####################
  # Lambda Resources #
  ####################
  CustomResource:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
        AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
        SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
        WorkspacePrefix: !Ref WorkspacePrefix
        CustomResourceLambdaS3Version: !Ref CustomResourceLambdaS3Version
        #VPCStackName: !Ref VPCStackName
        VPCStackName: !FindInMap
          - EnvironmentMap
          - !Ref Environment
          - VpcStackName
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${SharedBucketName}/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}/${Environment}/cf/nested/${S3Version}/custom-resource.cfn.yaml"

  HGResources:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
        AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
        SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
        WorkspacePrefix: !Ref WorkspacePrefix
        HGEventLambdaS3Version: !Ref HGEventLambdaS3Version
        HGEventRetryLambdaS3Version: !Ref HGEventRetryLambdaS3Version
        EventTopicArn: !Ref EventTopic
        #VPCStackName: !Ref VPCStackName
        VPCStackName: !FindInMap
          - EnvironmentMap
          - !Ref Environment
          - VpcStackName
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${SharedBucketName}/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}/${Environment}/cf/nested/${S3Version}/HG-subscriber.cfn.yaml"

  SBResources:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
        AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
        SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
        WorkspacePrefix: !Ref WorkspacePrefix
        SBEventLambdaS3Version: !Ref SBEventLambdaS3Version
        SBEventRetryLambdaS3Version: !Ref SBEventRetryLambdaS3Version
        EventTopicArn: !Ref EventTopic
        #VPCStackName: !Ref VPCStackName
        VPCStackName: !FindInMap
          - EnvironmentMap
          - !Ref Environment
          - VpcStackName
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${SharedBucketName}/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}/${Environment}/cf/nested/${S3Version}/SB-subscriber.cfn.yaml"

  BHResources:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
        AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
        SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
        WorkspacePrefix: !Ref WorkspacePrefix
        BHEventLambdaS3Version: !Ref BHEventLambdaS3Version
        BHEventRetryLambdaS3Version: !Ref BHEventRetryLambdaS3Version
        EventTopicArn: !Ref EventTopic
        #VPCStackName: !Ref VPCStackName
        VPCStackName: !FindInMap
        - EnvironmentMap
        - !Ref Environment
        - VpcStackName
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${SharedBucketName}/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}/${Environment}/cf/nested/${S3Version}/BH-subscriber.cfn.yaml"

  BHIResources:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
        AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
        SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
        WorkspacePrefix: !Ref WorkspacePrefix
        BHIEventLambdaS3Version: !Ref BHIEventLambdaS3Version
        BHIEventRetryLambdaS3Version: !Ref BHIEventRetryLambdaS3Version
        EventTopicArn: !Ref EventTopic
        #VPCStackName: !Ref VPCStackName
        VPCStackName: !FindInMap
          - EnvironmentMap
          - !Ref Environment
          - VpcStackName
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${SharedBucketName}/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}/${Environment}/cf/nested/${S3Version}/BHI-subscriber.cfn.yaml"

  AsoResources:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
        AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
        SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
        WorkspacePrefix: !Ref WorkspacePrefix
        AsoEventLambdaS3Version: !Ref AsoEventLambdaS3Version
        AsoEventRetryLambdaS3Version: !Ref AsoEventRetryLambdaS3Version
        EventTopicArn: !Ref EventTopic
        #VPCStackName: !Ref VPCStackName
        VPCStackName: !FindInMap
        - EnvironmentMap
        - !Ref Environment
        - VpcStackName
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${SharedBucketName}/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}/${Environment}/cf/nested/${S3Version}/aso-subscriber.cfn.yaml"

  CTResources:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AppName: !Ref AppName
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        DeveloperPrefix: !Ref DeveloperPrefix
        DeployPhase: !Ref DeployPhase
        AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
        SharedBucketName: !Ref SharedBucketName
        WorkspacePrefix: !Ref WorkspacePrefix
        CTEventLambdaS3Version: !Ref CTEventLambdaS3Version
        CTEventRetryLambdaS3Version: !Ref CTEventRetryLambdaS3Version
        EventTopicArn: !Ref EventTopic
        #VPCStackName: !Ref VPCStackName
        VPCStackName: !FindInMap
          - EnvironmentMap
          - !Ref Environment
          - VpcStackName
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${SharedBucketName}/${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}/${Environment}/cf/nested/${S3Version}/CT-subscriber.cfn.yaml"

  #########################
  # API Gateway Resources #
  #########################
  ApiGatewayDomainName:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    Properties:
      CertificateArn: !Join ["", ['arn:aws:acm:', !Ref 'AWS::Region', ':', !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', ':certificate/', !FindInMap [ EnvironmentMap, !Ref Environment, CertificateId ] ] ]
      DomainName: !Join [ '', [ !FindInMap [ EnvironmentMap, !Ref Environment, EnvironmentName ], !Ref HZ ] ]

  ApiBasePathMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    DependsOn: ApiDeployment20200214
    Properties:
      BasePath: ''
      DomainName: !Ref ApiGatewayDomainName
      RestApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi
      Stage: !Sub ${Environment}

  ApiGatewayARecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !FindInMap [ EnvironmentMap, !Ref Environment, HostedZoneId ]
      RecordSets:
        - Type: A
          Name: !Join  [ "", [ !FindInMap [ EnvironmentMap, !Ref Environment, EnvironmentName ], !Ref HZ, "." ] ]
          AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId: !Ref CloudFrontHZ
            DNSName: !GetAtt ApiGatewayDomainName.DistributionDomainName

  NaasRestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    DependsOn: EventTopic
    Properties:
      Body:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: 'AWS::Include'
          Parameters:
            Location: !Join ['/', [ 's3:/', !Ref SharedBucketName, !Ref WorkspacePrefix, 'naas.yaml' ]]

  RestApiStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiDeployment20200214
      RestApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi
      StageName: !Sub ${Environment}

  ApiDeployment20200214:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi

  TESTApiGatewayUsagePlan:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
    DependsOn: RestApiStage
    Properties:
      UsagePlanName: !Sub TEST-${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}-UsagePlan
      Description: !Sub 'TEST-${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase} Usage plan for Testing ONLY.'
      ApiStages:
        - ApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi
          Stage: !Sub ${Environment}
      Quota:
        Limit: 5000
        Offset: 0
        Period: DAY
      Throttle:
        BurstLimit: 150
        RateLimit: 100

  DefaultUsagePlan:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    DependsOn: RestApiStage
    Properties:
      UsagePlanName: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-Default-UsagePlan
      Description: !Sub '${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment} Default Usage plan for Brands'
      ApiStages:
        - ApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi
          Stage: !Sub ${Environment}
      Quota:
        Limit: 50000
        Offset: 0
        Period: DAY
      Throttle:
        BurstLimit: 1500
        RateLimit: 1000

  ApiGatewayNaasSNSRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}-ApiGatewayNaasSNSRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - apigateway.amazonaws.com
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess

  TESTApiKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
    DependsOn: RestApiStage
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "TEST-${DeveloperPrefix}${Environment}-${DeployPhase}"
      Description: "TEST API Key"
      Enabled: true
      StageKeys:
        - RestApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi
          StageName: !Sub ${Environment}

  CTApiKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    DependsOn: RestApiStage
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${DeveloperPrefix}CT-${Environment}"
      Description: !Sub "CT API Key"
      Enabled: true
      StageKeys:
        - RestApiId: !Ref NaasRestApi
          StageName: !Sub ${Environment}

  TESTUsagePlanKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey
    Properties:
      KeyId: !Ref TESTApiKey
      KeyType: API_KEY
      UsagePlanId: !Ref TESTApiGatewayUsagePlan

  CTUsagePlanKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    Properties:
      KeyId: !Ref CTApiKey
      KeyType: API_KEY
      UsagePlanId: !Ref DefaultUsagePlan

  ################################
  # Cognito User Pools Resources #
  ################################
  NaasUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}

  TESTUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      ClientName: 'TEST Brand'
      GenerateSecret: true
      UserPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool

  CTUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    Properties:
      ClientName: 'CT'
      GenerateSecret: true
      UserPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool

  UserPoolResourceServer:
    Type: Custom::CognitoUserPoolResourceServer
    DependsOn:
      - NaasRestApi
      - CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub ${CustomResource.Outputs.CustomResourceLambdaFunctionArn}
      RequestTypes:
        Create:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: createResourceServer
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.CreateResourceServerRequest'
          Parameters:
            userPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool
            name: NaaS
            identifier: naas
            scopes:
              - scopeName: "fraud.publish"
                scopeDescription: "Fraud Decision Change Event"
        Delete:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: deleteResourceServer
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.DeleteResourceServerRequest'
          Parameters:
            userPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool
            identifier: naas
        Update:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: updateResourceServer
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.UpdateResourceServerRequest'

  TESTBrandUserPoolClientSettings:
    Type: Custom::CognitoUserPoolClientSettings
    DependsOn: UserPoolResourceServer
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub ${CustomResource.Outputs.CustomResourceLambdaFunctionArn}
      RequestTypes:
        Create:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: updateUserPoolClientSettings
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.UpdateUserPoolClientRequest'
          Parameters:
            userPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool
            clientId: !Ref TESTUserPoolClient
            allowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true
            explicitAuthFlows:
              - 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH'
            supportedIdentityProviders:
              - COGNITO
            allowedOAuthFlows:
              - client_credentials
            allowedOAuthScopes:
              - 'naas/fraud.publish'
        Delete:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: deleteUserPoolClientSettings
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.DeleteUserPoolClientRequest'
          Parameters:
            userPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool
            clientId: !Ref TESTUserPoolClient
        Update:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: updateUserPoolClientSettings
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.UpdateUserPoolClientRequest'

  CTUserPoolClientSettings:
    Type: Custom::CognitoUserPoolClientSettings
    Condition: IsMainPipeline
    DependsOn: UserPoolResourceServer
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub ${CustomResource.Outputs.CustomResourceLambdaFunctionArn}
      RequestTypes:
        Create:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: updateUserPoolClientSettings
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.UpdateUserPoolClientRequest'
          Parameters:
            userPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool
            clientId: !Ref CTUserPoolClient
            allowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true
            explicitAuthFlows:
              - 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH'
            supportedIdentityProviders:
              - COGNITO
            allowedOAuthFlows:
              - client_credentials
            allowedOAuthScopes:
              - 'naas/fraud.publish'
        Delete:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: deleteUserPoolClientSettings
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.DeleteUserPoolClientRequest'
          Parameters:
            userPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool
            clientId: !Ref CTUserPoolClient
        Update:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: updateUserPoolClientSettings
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.UpdateUserPoolClientRequest'

  CognitoUserPoolDomain:
    Type: Custom::CreateCognitoUserPoolDomain
    DependsOn: CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub ${CustomResource.Outputs.CustomResourceLambdaFunctionArn}
      RequestTypes:
        Create:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: createUserPoolDomain
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.CreateUserPoolDomainRequest'
          Parameters:
            domain: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}
            userPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool
        Delete:
          Service: 'com.example.naas.lambda.cloudformation.service.CognitoService'
          Method: deleteUserPoolDomain
          Model: 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.DeleteUserPoolDomainRequest'
          Parameters:
            domain: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}${AppName}-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}
            userPoolId: !Ref NaasUserPool

  #################
  # SNS Resources #
  #################
  EventTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: !Sub '${DeveloperPrefix}event-${Environment}-${DeployPhase}'

  ##############################
  # Third-party Role Resources #
  ##############################
  SSMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${DeveloperPrefix}3rdPartySSMRole-${Environment}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: ''
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: arn:aws:iam::431055993173:root
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Condition:
              Bool:
                aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent: 'true'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub 3rdPartySSMRole-${Environment}
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Sid: SSMPermissions
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ssm:DescribeDocument
                  - ssm:GetDocument
                  - ssm:GetParameter
                  - ssm:GetParameters
                  - ssm:GetParametersByPath
                  - ssm:ListCommands
                  - ssm:ListDocuments
                  - ssm:CancelCommand
                  - ssm:PutParameter
                  - ssm:DeleteParameter
                  - ssm:SendCommand
                  - ssm:AddTagsToResource
                  - ssm:RemoveTagsFromResource
                Resource: !Join ['', ['arn:aws:ssm:', !Ref 'AWS::Region', ':', !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', ':', 'parameter/', 'third-party', '/', !Ref Environment,'/', '*']]
              - Sid: SSMDescribePermissions
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ssm:DescribeParameters
                Resource: '*'
              - Sid: KMSPermissions
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:ListAliases
                Resource: '*'


Outputs:
  SSMRoleName:
    Value: !Ref SSMRole
  SSMRoleNameArn:
    Value: !GetAtt SSMRole.Arn
```

Comment: Adding timestamp to a resource name will force re-creation of the resource upon update of the template. The lambda in question I assume is connected with API stage and stage update was necessary for scheme to work. Hard to say without seeing full template

Comment: Why should I have to force it's re-creation? Shouldn't I be able to update something without forcing something to be re-created?

Comment: When you change resource name, it will be treated as a new addition to the template. Therefore resource with old name will be removed from stack and resource with new name will take its place. CF doesn't look into "guts" of the resource to determine its uniqueness, it uses resource name as an ID. So if you change definition of resource but keep its name, then yes, upgrade takes place. Name changes - and it's a new resource.

Comment: I shouldn't have to change the name of the resource though - but if I don't the addition to the SNS topic doesn't work.

Comment: SNS topic and API resources don't influence each other directly, therefore CF has no reason to update API by itself. If topic was involved as a property somewhere (like `DomainName` property of BasePathMapping) then it would work that way.

Comment: Exactly - which is why I am wondering what is happening.

Comment: I feel like i'm lacking information here.. can you please post the entire template?

Comment: Posted @MariaInesParnisari Let me know if you want the CF for the nested stack in question where the resource is changed.

Comment: I'm confused... How is the API Gateway connected to the SNS subscription? They are both in two separate templates right? (i.e. the SNS is in a nested stack). If so, why do you expect the API gateway to be updated when you update the nested stack?

Comment: You have arrived at the heart of the problem I am seeking an answer for @MariaInesParnisari, this is the question I am asking.

Comment: It says [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html): "We strongly recommend that updates to nested stacks are run from the parent stack.". Did you do this? Did you try NOT changing the resource name of the API gateway and submitting the master stack update? (I think for this to work you would first have to update the template in S3 corresponding to the nested stack)

Comment: All of the updates were run from the parent stack and I described what occurred when we did NOT change the resource name. That situation is the whole basis for this question. I can replicate the problem quite easily and this has even stumped those at AWS support @MariaInesParnisari

Comment: Okay.. and how did you update the nested stack, did you update the template file in s3?

Comment: Yes, the template was updated in S3. It was deployed using CloudFormation with CodePipeline

Comment: What happens if you rename the s3 file and then change the master template to point to it, does it work?

Comment: I will have to test that @MariaInesParnisari, though I am not sure why renaming the S3 file would have anything to do with this problem.